# What's the order ships should go through an aleph when bomb running?

Tags: allegiance

What's the most effective way to have your bomb run break through a camp, assuming you can't "bait and switch" on another aleph?

Do you send bombers, figs or nans in first?

Answer (score 3):

Don't bomb through camped alephs!  If you have enough ints to break camp first, then, maybe send them, then the bomber, then the nans. If your bomber dies before the nans can reach it, it's something you could've avoided by not going.

Answer (score 0):

Send half the nans, then the bomber, then the rest of the nans.

If defended by other ships, they should accompany the first half of the nans.